# Программно решить систему линейных уравнений и неравенств

Tags: python, математика, matlab

Дана система нелинейных уравнений и неравенств.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Надо найти неизвестные переменные a1,a2,a3.
В прикрепленной системе неизвестные переменные это a1,a2,a3 и все присутствующие лямбды. С - это матрица 3х3. С_ij - элементы матрицы. То, что стоит в знаменателе (корень из (Сa,a)) можно расписать так, как расписано здесь.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

χ_β^N это тоже число, табличное значение. Это квантиль нормального распределения порядка бетта. В питоне должна быть функция какая-то, которая по значению бетта находит χ_β^N. На N внимание обращать не надо, это не в степень возводится, просто обозначение, что это нормальное распределение.В предпоследней строке еще есть коварная переменная альфа, ее очень легко спутать с "a"))
То есть на вход даются все переменные, кроме a1,a2,a3 и лямбд.
Решать можно на любом языке программирования, подойдет как Python, семейство Си и подобные, так и MatLab и Wolfram Matematica.
Не могу найти, как можно решать такого рода системы. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: На питоне можно посмотреть в сторону https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: @CrazyElf  я пытался там что-то искать, но не смог найти именно того метода, который смог бы решить задачу моего типа... Если Вы знаете, какие методы хотя бы примерно могут быть полезны и можете их подсказать, буду безумно благодарен)